# Orchard cms - custom forms - customize css for placement

Tags: orchardcms

I am just getting into orchard cms and i want to setup a custom form for taking some users details.

I have a form working as a widget and it posts back fine, but i'm having a hard time customizing the layout.

I can work out how to change the position of fields up or down, but i want to place some fields side-by-side instead of being stacked above each other, however each field is contained within it's own  tag, this tag has no id or class name associated with it so i can't adjust each individial fields css properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you have access to the form-widget template, in that case:

The best way is to add a class to the field so you can position the element with css.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Field, new { @class = "custom-class"})
```

@class add a the custom class to the input element generating this :

```
<input class="custom-class" id="Field.Id" name="Field.Title" type="text" value="">
```

Comment: im still learning...where would i find the form-widget template? I'm assuming this is some kind of EditorTemplate somewhere?

Comment: I recommed you to install Orchard.DesignerTools [link](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.DesignerTools) this tool will give a lot of info about the templates, shapes and models. Use it to look for the template. You can install the module from Orchard Backend. Here is a video-tutorial on how to use it [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqBHH4Du1bc)

Comment: ok that helped, i have created the correct file to override the html for my fields, but i'm having trouble with the correct @model directive. I have copied the code from the standard EditorTemplate.cshtml file, but getting this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'IShapeProxyda2c3434d03f442dbeb352861788a0a0', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Orchard.Fields.Fields.InputField

Comment: it seems there is a nested Model value which contains all the data, which is causing further issues with html helpers...such as Model.Model.SelectedValues.